# Java - volatile and visibility

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

As far as I have read, the underlying mechanism behind volatile guarantees no reordering of operations. However I am struggling to see how it guarantees visibility.

I.e. thread *A* writes a value. Then thread *B* reads it from memory, not from cache (to guarantee cache consistency). I know CAS does precisely this, but how does a memory barrier achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Volatile "uses" hardware specific instructions to achieve it. Here is [in-depth article about JSR-133 and Memory Barriers for Compiler Writers](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html)

> I know CAS does precisely this, but how does a mem barrier achieve this?

Because if you look for example inside `AtomicInteger`, you'll see

```
private volatile int value;
```

Comment: Ah, so there is flushing of the store buffers to main mem and cache invalidation...?

Comment: Yes, and cache "invalidation" on load - this is how changes are propagated, `StoreLoad` barrier.

Answer (score 1):

The memory barrier is implemented by the CPU to always show the latest value. This cannot be achieved without CPU support.

It is a common misconception that access is to main memory, however this would be very slow.  Instead there is a cache coherence bus between L2 caches.

There is a write store buffer before the L1 cache, but the CPU makes sure the cache line is current between cores.

Comment: Yes, but saying "it is implemented by the cpubto show the latest value" is slightlybtoo high level for me. How is it achieved? Are store buffers flushed?

Comment: Too generic and intel-specific.

Comment: @Bober02, you seem to be asking a question about computer architecture, which may be beyond the scope of this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Generic memory barrier is a CPU-specific instructions, which says 'invalidate your read cache' or 'commit your write cache', or both. On strong-ordering CPUs like x86 there 'invalidate your read cache' is a no-op, since caches are always coherent.